# Export SharePoint List to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, export-to-excel

I have been getting an error when I try to export a Contacts list from our SharePoint online environment to excel. It downloads a query file but says "*Cannot connect to the server at this time. Changes to your data cannot be saved.*" when attempting to open it.

I found this as an example but it does not work.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

I have tried with Excel 2016 and Excel Online.

Answer (score 0):

Does the issue exists in other lists? Can you export custom list to excel? 
Create a new contact list and compare whether you can export it excel.

Can other users with full control permission export that contact list to excel?

As an option workaround, follow the below steps:

Open Excel.

Go to "Data" tab from top menu.

Click on "From Web" from the menu items.

Connect your site with this.

Import the data.

Now go back to the IE and export List (which you were doing previously).

The List will be exported.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c779151e-681b-4d5b-a43f-034c7f2b8bad/excel-cannot-connect-to-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: I have tried a custom list and the calendar list with the same result. Also tried a different tenant and still the same. Have had others with site collection admin permissions try in both tenants try also same results. Have tried accessing through Data tab in Excel and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I would suggest you open a service request.